# Can I expand a tuple to nowhere?

Tags: python

If I have a function that returns a bunch of stuff, I'd like to just grab one thing that it returns and discard the rest, without having to assign it and then delete it. I'm trying to conserve memory when working with large datasets.

```
def function(a, b)
    return a, b

x, _ = function(A, B)
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Well, what happens when you execute this?  Don't ask *us*, we're only humans.  The Python interpreter is your final arbiter.  :-)

Comment: Yes, but only if you add a `:` at the end of `def` line.

Comment: I suspect you will want to know about python *generators* -- basically, lazy sequences. Set up your function right and you can iterate until you get to the part you want, and never continue. Read about it, but if you want more specifics, you'll need to give more details about what your function does.

Comment: Note that the second element of that tuple still *exists*, for the brief lifetime of the tuple.  Never assigning it to anything, or assigning it and then dropping the variable, have exactly the same memory requirements.

Comment: If you really don't want to use some of the output of the function, maybe you should try not to create it in the first place. Assigning the useless returned data to some variable makes no difference in the amount of memory used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do

```
def function(a, b):
    return a, b

x = function(A, B)[0]
```

The reference counter of the intermediate tuple should hit zero and thus be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will run and produce the value you expect: `x` will be assigned the value in `A`. However, in Python `_` is a valid variable name, so you're also creating a variable called `_` and assigning it the value in `B`. It seems that you want only the first value to be assigned to a variable so this is probably not great for you. Note that changing that code to:

```
x = function(A, B)
```

would mean that `x` would be equal to `(A, B)` which is also not what you want.

So, then the question you need to ask yourself is: why does this method return two values and why am I discarding one of them? If this is a method you wrote then perhaps it would make sense to split the functionality out into separate methods so you avoid "wasting" the returned value or perhaps you actually need that second value and you just haven't thought that far ahead. Of course, if this method is actually not yours then the point is moot, in which case using the `_` as a placeholder is probably your best bet.